# Netbeans 8 - Apache Cordova Issue

Tags: cordova, netbeans

i've an issue making Cordova Project on Netbeans 8.0.1 on Windows 7

I followed this step (after googling and searching hours and hours)

1) Downloading and installing netbeans 8
2) Download and installing node.js
3) run the command > npm install -g cordova (download and installed latest cordova 4)
4) download and install git

5) verify that the commands:

> "cordova  --version" --> 4.0.0
>
> "git  --version" --> git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2

5bis) Added npm directory and git/bin to PATH variable

6) Reboot machine

7) Open netbeans -> new project -> html5 > cordova

And here i'm getting once again "Netbeans cannot find cordova or git in your PATH. Please install cordova and git".

What i'm doing wrong? 
If i run from command > npm create TestProject
cordova succesfully create project dir, why netbeans doesn't recognize nor cordova and git?

Note: netbeans give me the following error:

[org.netbeans.modules.cordova.CordovaPlatform$Version]: Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2

Answer (score 1):

Have you used Git installer from [here](http://git-scm.com/download/win) or some other? If other, I would try to reinstall Git. The message `Netbeans cannot find cordova or git in your PATH. Please install cordova and git` is displayed if either git or cordova or both are not found (in other words, it does not necessary mean that cordova is not recognized it could be the git)

Comment: Yes, git was the problem, i've installed git from git-scm.com but while netbeans 7.4 works like a charm, netbeans 8 didn't.
And i don't know why, however i solved whit downgrading to netbeans 7.4.
If i run the project netbeans 8 says:
[org.netbeans.modules.cordova.CordovaPlatform$Version]: Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2

Comment: Downgrading is not the best solution, NetBeans 8.0.1 contains quite some improvements and fixes. It could be useful it you report issue to https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/ and attach all possible information including IDE log (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install an older version of cordova(3.6.3-0.2.13). It's worked for me.